# field separation during browser resize

Tags: forms, field, autoresizingmask

I have this template I'm working on and it's resizeable from full screen to the width of an iphone. My contact form field is fine at full screen, but when I resize my browser, it seperates really bad and not sure how to fix this to keep the fields right under each other. I have a before/after here:

http://www.webauthorsgroup.com/before.jpg
http://www.webauthorsgroup.com/after.jpg